# VL53L0x sensor Ranging error. How to solve the error?

Tags: arm, embedded, atmel, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to interface vl53l0x sensor with my atSamE51A19 controller. I can send the data to the sensor. As it has established connection I send identification code and it responds. But further initialization and ranging is not working.

I'm using stm library implementation on my sam board. [stmArduinoLib][1]
The only changes I made is in the read write functions. It was using stm base functions but I'm using different functions.

```
    /****************** Write and read functions from I2C *************************/

VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X::VL53L0X_WriteMulti(VL53L0X_DEV Dev, uint8_t index, uint8_t *pdata, uint32_t count)
{
    int status;

    status = VL53L0X_I2CWrite(index, pdata, (uint16_t) count);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_CONTROL_INTERFACE;
    }
    else
    {
        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return status;      
}

VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X::VL53L0X_ReadMulti(VL53L0X_DEV Dev, uint8_t index, uint8_t *pdata, uint32_t count)
{
    int status;

    if (count >= VL53L0X_MAX_I2C_XFER_SIZE)
    {
        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMS;
    }

    status = VL53L0X_I2CRead(index, pdata, (uint16_t) count);

    return status;  
}

VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X::VL53L0X_WrByte(VL53L0X_DEV Dev, uint8_t index, uint8_t data)
{
    int status;

    status = WriteRegister(index, data);    //VL53L0X_I2CWrite(index, &data, 1);

    if (status == 0)
    {
        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_CONTROL_INTERFACE;
    }
    else
    {
        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE;
    }

    return status;  
}

VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X::VL53L0X_WrWord(VL53L0X_DEV Dev, uint8_t index, uint16_t data)
{
    int status;
    int32_t status_int;
    alignas(2) uint8_t buffer[2];

    buffer[0] = data >> 8;
    buffer[1] = data & 0x00FF;

    status_int = VL53L0X_I2CWrite(index, (uint8_t*) buffer, 2);

    // buffer[0] = MSB
    // buffer[1]
    // buffer[2]
    // buffer[3] = LSB
    if (status_int == 0)
    {
        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_CONTROL_INTERFACE;
    }
    else
    {
        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE;
    }

    return status;  
}

VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X::VL53L0X_WrDWord(VL53L0X_DEV Dev, uint8_t index, uint32_t data)
{
    int status;
    int32_t status_int;
    alignas(2) uint8_t buffer[4];

    buffer[0] = (data >> 24) & 0xFF;                // MSB
    buffer[1] = (data >> 16) & 0xFF;
    buffer[2] = (data >> 8) & 0xFF;
    buffer[3] = (data >> 0) & 0xFF;                 // LSB
    status_int = VL53L0X_I2CWrite(index, buffer, 4);

    if (status_int == 0)
    {
        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_CONTROL_INTERFACE;
    }
    else
    {
        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE;
    }

    return status;  
}

VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X::VL53L0X_RdByte(VL53L0X_DEV Dev, uint8_t index, uint8_t *data)
{
    int status = VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE;

    status = ReadRegister(index, *data);    //
    if (status)
    {
        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE;
        return status;
    }
    else
    {
        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_CONTROL_INTERFACE;
    }
    return status;
}

VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X::VL53L0X_RdWord(VL53L0X_DEV Dev, uint8_t index, uint16_t *data)
{
    int status = 0;
    uint8_t buffer[2] =
    { 0, 0 };

    status = VL53L0X_I2CRead(index, buffer, 2);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        *data = (uint16_t) (buffer[0] << 8) | (buffer[1] & 0xFF);       // | ? +
    }

    return status;          
}

VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X::VL53L0X_RdDWord(VL53L0X_DEV Dev, uint8_t index, uint32_t *data)
{
    int status;
    uint8_t buffer[4] =
    { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    status = VL53L0X_I2CRead(index, buffer, 4);
    if (!status)                                    // use OR
    {
        *data = ((uint32_t) buffer[0] << 24) | ((uint32_t) buffer[1] << 16) | ((uint32_t) buffer[2] << 8) | (uint32_t) buffer[3];
    }
    return status;

}

VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X::VL53L0X_UpdateByte(VL53L0X_DEV Dev, uint8_t index, uint8_t AndData, uint8_t OrData)
{
    int status;
    uint8_t buffer = 0;

    /* read data direct onto buffer */
    status = VL53L0X_I2CRead(index, &buffer, 1);
    if (!status)
    {
        buffer = (buffer & AndData) | OrData;
        status = VL53L0X_I2CWrite(index, &buffer, (uint8_t) 1);
    }

    if (status == 0)
    {
        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_CONTROL_INTERFACE;
    }
    else
    {

        status = VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return status;
}

VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X::VL53L0X_I2CWrite(uint8_t RegisterAddr, uint8_t *pBuffer, uint16_t NumByteToWrite)
{
    return WriteRegisters(RegisterAddr, pBuffer, NumByteToWrite);
}

VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X::VL53L0X_I2CRead(uint8_t RegisterAddr, uint8_t *pBuffer, uint16_t NumByteToRead)
{
    alignas(2) uint8_t vpBuffer[5];
    /*  dev_i2c->beginTransmission(((uint8_t) (((DeviceAddr) >> 1) & 0x7F)));
     */

    if (ReadRegisters(RegisterAddr, vpBuffer, NumByteToRead))
    {
        pBuffer = vpBuffer;
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

In this functions I'm not sending device address everytime just sending the index and data. In constructor only I've set the address once. The only error I'm getting when I use Status = `VL53L0X_PerformRefSpadManagement(Device, &refSpadCount, &isApertureSpads);` This function. In initialization. Don't know how to solve this issue. Tried to change the mode to continous that didn't help. Note: the sensor is working fine with arduino.
[1]: https://github.com/stm32duino/VL53L0X

Answer (score 1):

I found a new possible solution to this problem, as I spent 2 days to solve it, I feel that I need to share it with you guys. Here is the summary of solutions:

1. *Powering problem 1*: **add a 50ms delay in the setup function** (before the sensor init, obviously). This way, the Vin will have time enough to reach the level needed by the sensor, as explained in a previous message (ocrdu)
2. *Powering problem 2*: This sensor demands more than others, normally the **5V pin of your board will do it better than the 3v3**. If there are many sensors connected at the same time, **disconnect all of them to check whether they are using the power our vl53l0x needs**.
3. *Powering problem 3*: If you feed it with an external source, **unify grounds with the board**, don't forget it
4. *SCL - SDA weak signals*: **add a pullup (2k2 - 4k7 from each channel to vin)**, this way the signals will perform better, that could be the problem
5. *Soldering problem*: **Make sure that each header pin is well soldered**. I've found many cases of poor soldering. The tiny pads don't help. It is advisable to check continuity with a multimeter between the headers and the pads where they should be connected
6. *XSHUT not pulled up*: My problem, this was that AZDelivery board says that it has a pull up in XSHUT (which works like an enable). But it could either be false, or badly implemented. **Xshut needs to be high, 3v3/5v**, otherwise, the sensor won't work. Bridge the XSHUT to Vin or implement a pull up and the problem will be solved.

- **I am using adafruit's library 1.1.2, and it works, with pullups, without pullups, connected to 5V and also connected to 3V3, with the
  50ms delay, and connecting XSHUT to high (3V3 / Vin)**
- **My board is vl53l0x from AZDelivery (5€ amazon)**
- **I have tested the sensor with arduino nano and with ESP32, both work fine**

Hope you guys find this useful <3